# To read csv file in mulesoft using IBM MQ "On New Message" connector

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to do a POC, to read a csv file in Mulesoft using IBM MQ Connector

I am using "**On New Message**" node to read the message
My csv file does not have header row and I am trying to read the first row records but not able to read it.
Providing input directive header=false in Transform message is not working.

I am looking for a way to provide this information on "On New message" node itself.

For other connector like HTTP Listener, we can set MIME type as application csv and add parameter header=false.

code

%dw 2.0

input payload application/csv header=false

output application/csv header=false

---

payload[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the on new message listener you should be able to set the outputMimeType attribute with the "input" format configuration. It seems for this connector it is called Content Type (https://docs.mulesoft.com/ibm-mq-connector/1.6/ibm-mq-xml-ref#listener).:There is no input directive in DataWeave 2. You have to set the type at the connector operation/listener level.

Comment: yes, i can set 'application/csv' in Content Type  under 'Media Type Overriding' section. I am looking for property where I can set 'header= false'

Comment: Next to the mime  type like in the examples at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats#reader_writer_properties